# Global not defined when running a JS script in a Java application

Tags: javascript, java

I have a js script which I want to execute in my Java application.

I have tried to use the `Chromedriver` API to do this

But it throws the following exception:

[image: global not defined]

I am so confused because the script can simply run with `node xx.js`

**Does this mean the js which uses the `global` object cannot execute in a Java application?**

Comment: Can you post the code? Screenshot of an error is not enough to help with a solution.

Comment: Now that [Nashorn has been removed](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372), I would use [Rhino](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object), `global` is Node-specific, so you can't expect to be able to use it if you're not running under Node. They suggest [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) as the portable replacement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, By replacing the `golbal` with the `globalThis` ,it finally works.